# Как разбить строку в Java?

Tags: java, строки

Есть строка:

```
String="Moscow,Astana,London";
```

Нужно получить:

```
String 1=Moscow;
String 2=Astana;
String 3=London;
```

Comment: `String string = "my,some,string"; String[] strings = string.split(",");` в результате: `strings[0] == "my"`, `strings[1] == "some"`, `strings[2] == "string"`.

Comment: если вам дали правильный ответ, отметьте его галкой напротив для тех, кто в дальнейшем наткнется на эту тему.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Используйте [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-). Думаю, должно быть что-то типа `String.split(",");` для получения нужного вам списка.

Answer (score 1):

С использованием stream'ов решение будет такое:

```
String str = "String=\"Moscow,Astana,London\"";
String result = Arrays
            .stream(str.substring(str.indexOf("=\"") + 2, str.length() - 1).split(","))
            .map(city -> str.substring(0, str.indexOf("=\"")) + "=" + city)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(";", "", ";"));
System.out.println(result);
```